# about this smart pointer class

Tags: c++

I run into this code in a book, a simple smart pointer, have a few questions about it:

```
    template <class T>
class SmartPointer {
 public:
    SmartPointer(T * ptr) {
        ref = ptr;
        ref_count = malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
        *ref_count = 1;
    }
    SmartPointer(SmartPointer<T> & sptr) {
        ref = sptr.ref;
        ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
        ++*ref_count;
    }
    SmartPointer<T> & operator=(SmartPointer<T> & sptr) {
        if (this != &sptr) {
           ref = sptr.ref;
           ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
           ++*ref_count;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~SmartPointer() {
        --*ref_count;
        if (*ref_count == 0) {
           delete ref;
           free(ref_count);
           ref = ref_count = NULL;
        }
    }
    T* operator->() { return ref; }
    T& operator*() { return *ref; }
 protected:
    T * ref;
    unsigned * ref_count; 
};
```

here are my questions:
 1. why is the ref_count initialized by using malloc? why can't it be ref_count = new unsigned();
 2. the = operator function, doesn't it need to clean up the old value? this code seems to cause a ref counting error.

Thanks,

Comment: What book is it? Has anyone tried to compile this: `ref = ref_count = NULL`?

Comment: That's one of the few parts of it that *are* valid.

Comment: I thought you can't assign `unsigned*` to `T*` for arbitrary `T`.

Comment: Hm, good point. You can't. It's fail.

Answer (score 3):

This book you have is rubbish. You need to throw it away. This code doesn't even compile.

1. `malloc` is not any better than `new unsigned(1)`. `malloc()` returns `void*` which needs to be cast to `unsigned*` which is obviously not done here.
2. You are right, the reference count of the object previously pointed to needs to be taken care of.

Why not try looking into the implementation of `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`? It's very likely that you'll end up using it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> **why is the ref_count initialized by using `malloc`?**

It can use `std::new` as well. The primary difference between `new` and `malloc` is that `new` provides an opportunity to suitably initialize your object by calling its constructor in addition to allocating dynamic memory.In case of in-built data type like `unsigned int`(as in your example code) essentially this important difference doesn't matter.
Note that usually `std::new` implementations also essentially call a `malloc` for memory allocation.

> **The `= operator` function, doesn't it need to clean up the old value? this code seems to cause a ref counting error**

Indeed there is an error.
The `= operator` in this implementation checks if the pointer is being assigned to itself and if yes it correctly increases the reference count by `1`, Since there is one more entity which shares this pointer after the `=` is called.
If the scenario is not self assignment then the implementation should reduce the reference count of the pointer being assigned to by `1`, check if the count is `0` and if it is zero, deallocate the same.

Comment: What if `this` was pointing to something else? Doesn't a reference count need to be decreased?

Comment: @AlexanderChertov: And when will such a situation arise? An `=` will never lead to decrement in reference count.The count only needs to be decreased when an entity loses ownership of the said object, which is when destructor is called.

Comment: `SmartPointer<int> a( (new int ) ); SmartPointer<int> b( (new int ) ); a = b;`

Comment: @AlexanderChertov: Indeed I overlooked.Modifed for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad code. Self-assignment is non-idiomatic, awful use of `malloc`, buggy reference counting implementation, no `const` on the copy assignment operator/constructor argument, and doesn't deal with `SmartPointer`s that point to NULL. Throw your book away and get one that works.